# return 404 if .php is requested

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file looks like this in order to make my urls from /something.php to /something :

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

When requested the php extension, it still works. How can i return a 404 if the .php extension is requested? thank you.

Comment: Please explain again and in more words what you are attempting. Use an example.

Comment: i want it to return a 404 error if someone were to type in the .php file extension in the url. since the code i provided removes the .php extension but still enables the user to type it in.

Comment: You actually want to return HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found or just redirect to your custom 404 page?

Comment: redirect to 404 page sorry

Answer (score 1):

First, your approach should be shortened to:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This probes for existence of the .php file, not for absence of its basename.

Since this is the `[LAST]` rule, you can afterwards (or possibly before the RewriteRule/RewriteCond block) probe for already-present .php suffixes:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ - [F]
```

... or issue a redirect in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
  <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L,S]
  </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: If you use response code values outside of range 300-399 you will essentially destroy the rewrite chain which is why you don't want to do that (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)
Here it might not present a big problem but in more complicated rules it will definitely account for some headache.